# What are the correct terms for "open accounts" and "closed accounts"?

Tags: translation

As the title indicates, I'm asking what the correct terms for "open accounts" and "closed accounts" are where "accounts" refers to a list of financial accounts (bank accounts, credit card accounts, etc.) that are either open or permanently closed.

My best guess is that the English words "open" and "closed" should correspond to the Chinese words "active" (活動的) and "inactive" (不活動的) in this case, but, I'm not sure, particularly since the meanings of "inactive" and "permanently closed" don't align. Perhaps I should pair 活動的 with 關閉的 instead?

Answer (score 4):

To  open an account  开账户

To close an account 注销账户

Active account  活跃账户 （mostly used for internet accounts）

Inactive account 沉睡账户 （mostly used for internet accounts）

Answer (score 2):

開帳戶(open account), 關帳戶(close account), 活帳戶(active account), 呆帳戶 (inactive account), 死帳戶 (permanently closed account).